# Wordpress: Need to post multilanguage Post

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new for Wordpress, I have created one blog for learning purpose, and would like to work with multi language in that.
I mean, there are different posts in the blog. Just like a news, I want to post mixed language news, i.e.

1) My first news is in English language, and I have posted it.
2) Now for the second Post I want to post in other language i.e (Gujarati, Hindi, French or any other language.)

Now the problem is, When I am Publishing My Post, Post will added, but garbage characters takes place in place of it. (??????? like message will appear in other languages. only English Language post I can see proper.)
**- Even I have tried Xii-language Plugin, but steel not able to use multi Language.**

So is anyone help me for that?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of handy language plugins. Try `qTranslate` or `WPML`, I personally do not have any issues with language characters while using `WPML`.

One thing to remember is, that you have to post your content in *Visual editor*, not in *HTML* mode.

Also make sure that **your theme's font** support those languages. If unsure, try using a font from Google Web fonts, which support Hindi or Gujarati. Include this font in your `style.css` file and check the result.

Example for your `style.css` :

`@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/lohitdevanagari.css);
body {font-family: 'Lohit Devanagari', serif;}`

You will now be able to display Hindi on your web-site. The `Google API` will be delivered through a content delivery network (CDN) so the loading time of these fonts is minimal - at least, it won't cause your web applications to load slower.

Comment: Sorry but I am still facing the same problem. My record will be inserted as (?????) in database.

Comment: Try to use in your Administration area different font (the same Hindi) for editing. Read this article for how-to http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-change-fonts-on-visual-editor-mode?replies=14

Comment: If that article doesn't work, try wordpress.stackexchange.com